# Message part x is not recognized. Does it exist in service WSDL? case sensitivity?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, apache-camel

I am using the camel-cxf libs to try make a very basic web service client.

The error I get is:

```
Message part {http://tariffservice.agw.mycompany.com/}getTariffPrice 
was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?):
```

The WSDL was created by the .NET guys because their side doesn't work if I generate WSDLs in the Java fashion.  So if I look in the WSDL, I see the correct name for the method is: GetTariffPrice.  In fact, no where is there a lowercase getTariffPrice in any of the annotations.  It's only the method name that's lowercase.

So I get the feeling like that's the problem, but I don't know where to fix it.  CXF autogenerates the files every time I compile.  Is there a binding file maybe?

----  Edit:  Reply to Willem's q

I used the camel-master cxf example, which was in code for whatever reason.  The WSDL has GetTariffPrice everywhere, which makes me think if I could get CXF to generate GetTariffPrice instead of getTariffPrice, it might work

```
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/tariffAdmin/services/tariffEndpoint";

protected static ITariffService createCXFClient() {
    // we use CXF to create a client for us as its easier than JAXWS and works
    ClientProxyFactoryBean factory = new ClientProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(ITariffService.class);
    factory.setAddress(URL);
    return (ITariffService) factory.create();
}

    ITariffService service = createCXFClient();
    TariffPriceResponse response = service.getTariffPrice(request);
```

---- Further edit:

I told Maven not to build my classes, and then changed the method name from getTariffPrice to GetTariffPrice, in the generated client class.  I now get this message:

```
Unexpected wrapper element {http://tariffservice.agw.company.com/}GetTariffPrice found.   Expected {http://agw.company.com/tariffservice}GetTariffPrice.
```

Hmm.

Comment: Can you show us your camel route?

Comment: added details - I am basing off org.apache.camel.example.cxf.CamelRouteClient code

Comment: Ok, I gave up.  Switched to JAX-WS.  Working now.

Comment: You need to use JaxWsProxyFactoryBean to create the proxy, it will take the annotation of serviceClass into consideration.